# Paypal SDK Integration Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paypal

I am trying to add the Paypal SDK to my app but I get 4 errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
  ___clang_call_terminate in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
  ___clang_call_terminate in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

- Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags
- Add -lc++ & -ObjC to it

This worked for me solve errors same as above.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags Add -ObjC -l"PayPalMobile" -l"Pods-PayPal-iOS-SDK" -l"c++" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "SystemConfiguration"
```